# How to resolve IoC dynamically by using it's name as string

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

I have a multiple Implementations for the same interface like the below example

```
container.Register(Component.For<OrganizationServiceCore.IOrganizationService>().ImplementedBy<SchoolServiceCore.SchoolsProvider.SchoolService>());
```

OR

```
 container.Register(Component.For<OrganizationServiceCore.IOrganizationService>().ImplementedBy<CompanyServiceCore.CompanyProvider.CompanyService>());
```

The resolving must depend on a vale in the database,I will get the value from database as a string "SchoolServiceCore.SchoolsProvider.SchoolService" OR
"CompanyServiceCore.CompanyProvider.CompanyService"

How I can use it like the example below:

```
string serviceName= "CompanyServiceCore.CompanyProvider.CompanyService";

 container.Register(Component.For<OrganizationServiceCore.IOrganizationService>().ImplementedBy<serviceName>());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     var assemblyName = "CompanyServiceCore.CompanyProvider";
     var serviceName = "CompanyService";
        System.Reflection.Assembly assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(assemblyName);

     var service = assembly.GetTypes().Where(p =>
                                     p.FullName == assemblyName+"."+serviceName
                                ).FirstOrDefault();

        container.Register(Component.For<OrganizationServiceCore.IOrganizationService>().ImplementedBy(service));
```

you can change the assemblyName and serviceName variables depending on the needed value.

don't forgot to add the project reference on the place that you want to use it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using

```cs
string serviceName= "CompanyServiceCore.CompanyProvider.CompanyService";
Type myType= Type.GetType(serviceName);
container.Register(Component.For<OrganizationServiceCore.IOrganizationService>().ImplementedBy<myType>());
```

and using this to register your type in the IoC container.

Comment: in its current form, the code you've written will not compile - you can't use a variable as the generic type parameter

Answer (score 1):

I would assume that you are using **Windsor Castle** as your DI container based on the provided sample code.

I can see at least two different options:
1) Register All and use only the appropriate one

```
container.Register(
   Component.For<OrganizationServiceCore.IOrganizationService>()
     .ImplementedBy<SchoolServiceCore.SchoolsProvider.SchoolService>(),
   Component.For<OrganizationServiceCore.IOrganizationService>()
     .ImplementedBy<CompanyServiceCore.CompanyProvider.CompanyService>());
```

In this case the first one would win. But if you call the `Named` builder function as well during the service registrations then you can resolve the appropriate one by its name.

```
container.Register(
   Component.For<OrganizationServiceCore.IOrganizationService>()
     .Named("SchoolService")
     .ImplementedBy<SchoolServiceCore.SchoolsProvider.SchoolService>(),
   Component.For<OrganizationServiceCore.IOrganizationService>()
     .Named("CompanyService")
     .ImplementedBy<CompanyServiceCore.CompanyProvider.CompanyService>());
```

...

```
 IOrganizationService svc = container.Resolve<IOrganizationService>("SchoolService");
```

2) Register only the ONE that is needed
In this case you should use `UsingFactoryMethod` builder function to delegate the creation process of the appropriate service implementation.

```
 container.Register(
     Component.For<OrganizationServiceCore.IOrganizationService>()
        .UsingFactoryMethod(
          () => OrganizationServiceFactory.CreateService(serviceNameSetting)));
```

Comparison

- The first approach allows to use multiple implementation at the same
  time
- The first approach chooses the appropriate implementation on
  the usage side (this is the so called Service Locator pattern, which
  should be avoided if possible if you use DI already)
- The second approach registers only a single implementation
- The second approach separates registration logic from type deduction logic

For further information please visit the [Windsor documentation](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/registering-components-one-by-one.md)